# Select specific tabs with Command-# key in Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is there any way to mimic Chrome's behavior of selecting specific tabs with a Command-# combination (e.g., Command-1 selects Tab 1, Command-2 selects Tab 2, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not something you can do out-of-the-box, but there are ways to hack around that. This article will give details:

http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2012/2423

Essentially, the trick is to create a series of scripts and use something like FastScripts (or something like Alfred or LaunchBar) to run the scripts.

Comment: Please excerpt or summarize linked articles, instead of just posting a link.